# How can I style a second level child differently than a first level child?

Tags: html, css

I want the second level ols to have uppercase alpha list styling and the first level ols to have uppercase Roman. I tried using the child combinator, and I assumed that the more specific styling would override the less specific styling, but that doesn't seem to be the case. This is for an assignment, so I can't change the HTML to give the first level ol an ID. It has to be done through the CSS. I assume there's something I'm missing here about how the child combinator works.

```css
#outline > ol {
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  list-style: upper-roman;
}

#outline > ol > ol {
  list-style: upper-alpha;
}
```

```html
<nav id="outline">
      <h1>Course Outline</h1>
      <ol>
        <li>
          <a href="#">The Road to War</a>
          <ol>
            <li><a href="#">Planting the Seeds</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The First Crisis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Compromise &amp; Failure</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fault Lines</a></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Politicians &amp; Generals</a>
          <ol>
            <li><a href="#">The Election of 1860</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Politicians</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Generals</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Election of 1864</a></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">The Course of War</a>
          <ol>
            <li><a href="#">The Anaconda Plan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Eastern Campaign</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Western Campaign</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1861-1862</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1863</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1864-1865</a></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Aftermath</a>
          <ol>
            <li><a href="#">Lincoln Assassination</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reconstruction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">A New Constitution</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The United States Is ...</a></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Just change #outline > ol  > ol to #outline > ol  ol.  The second ol is not a direct child of the first ol as there's a li element between them

Comment: Agree with adam. child combinator only works for direct children, not children of children. Another alternative would be `#outline > ol > li > ol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an `li` in the middle. So when using the immediate child selector `>` need to consider it.

```css
#outline>ol {
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  list-style: upper-roman;
}

#outline>ol>li>ol {
  list-style: upper-alpha;
}
```

```html
<nav id="outline">
  <h1>Course Outline</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="#">The Road to War</a>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="#">Planting the Seeds</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The First Crisis</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Politicians &amp; Generals</a>
      <ol>
        <li><a href="#">The Election of 1860</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Politicians</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of using ID selector, we can get the required output with class selector itself**
*Here i declared class selector names as "first-level-child" and "second-level-child", now using html class attribute, assign class name to respective child elements to apply the respective CSS properties*

```
.first-level-child {
    line-height: 2em;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    list-style: upper-roman;
    color: black;
  }
  
 .second-level-child {
    list-style: upper-alpha;
 }
```

```
<ol>
<li>
<a href="#">The Road to War</a>
    <ol class="first-level-child">
        <li><a href="#">Planting the Seeds</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The First Crisis</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Compromise &amp; Failure</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fault Lines</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li >
    <a href="#">Politicians &amp; Generals</a>
        <ol class="second-level-child">
            <li><a href="#">The Election of 1860</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Politicians</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Generals</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Election of 1864</a></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```